# Write-ups vs Writings

Tags: differences

What is the difference between the mentioned two words?

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. I look forward to reading more of your write-ups.
2. I look forward to reading more of your writings.

Comment: Do you have any information on what your friends are writing? All of their written material make up writings. but only certain materials (reports and reviews) are write-ups.

Comment: It's a writing on physics related topic but thank you. It's clear now.